# Why do LED's glow when taken out

Tags: led, plug

Why do LED's keep alight when taken out the socket, and then eventually fade. With any other bulb shouldnt it go out instantly. For example my phone charger has an LED which indicates to whether my phone is charging, however, when i unplug the plug it stays on for a little bit and then fades to nothing. Why does this happen? Is it to do with there being a little bit of current still flowing or something?

Comment: Because capacitors are a thing.

Comment: What is an "LED"? You mention "socket", but then also mention your phone.... An "LED" in your house lamp is actually a mildy complicated device that converts house AC voltage to something that powers multiple LEDs in the bulb. The LED in your phone is a single LED (well actually it's likely 3 "LEDs" in one housing (Red/Green/Blue)) and those are controlled by the phone, the timing of which is not at all related to the slow dimming of a house bulb.

Comment: im talking about an led light on the actual plug

Comment: I doubt anyone knows what you're referring to because 'actual plug' doesn't really describe anything in particular, and none of the plugs I'm aware of have LEDs in them.

Comment: Cameron, you must be explicit. "light on the actual plug" means very little. You phone has a light on the plug? Hint: One extra sentence isn't going to help. I imagine you'll need at least 5 or 6 to even begin to fully explain what you think an LED is and how you'd like us to explain. Pretend as if we can't read your mind and then explain what you mean.

Comment: `LED's keep alight when taken out the socket` ... how are you unplugging the LED from the device? .... is the device case opened?

Comment: The phosphor in the LED glows for a while after turn off (same with CFL's), and there is also some charge to bleed off in the capacitors

Answer (score 2):

LEDs on their own do not glow when taken out.

LEDs in power supplies may glow and fade out if the power supply is disconnected from mains. This is due to the capacitors in the power supply. Capacitors hold charge between pulses of alternating current (AC) found in the mains and inside the power-supply itself. These act a bit like a short-term battery and power the LED temporarily. The voltage will decrease at a rate depending on the electrical load and the LED will fade in consequence.

[image]

*Figure 1. A switched mode power supply showing (1) the high-voltage capacitor and (2) the low-voltage smoothing capacitor. Both will keep the output voltage up for a short while. Source: [SMPS.us](http://www.smps.us/power-supply.html).*

Comment: White LEDs can show a faint glow because of the phosphor but I guess that is quite irrelevant for a typical indicator LED which is a single color typically...

Answer (score 0):

This is because the charger has a capacitor on its low voltage output for smoothing the output voltage. Without that capacitor, the voltage would have a ripple of a few volts.

That capacitor is sized for the expected output current. If you unplug the low voltage of your charger from the phone, the load is much much smaller – it's just the LED left. That's why it takes a few seconds to empty the capacitor which actual purpose is to reduce ripple in the milliseconds range.